# NixOS: some user-subscribed channels are not shown by `nix-channel --list`, how to remove them (unsubscribe)?

Tags: nixos, nix

I am confused by the current state of my channel subscription on NixOS.  It seems that I have a per-user subscription to `nixos-17.03` and `nixos-17.09`:

```
$ nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info -m"
 - system: `"x86_64-linux"`
 - host os: `Linux 4.19.13, NixOS, 18.09.1853.c2950341d03 (Jellyfish)`
 - multi-user?: `yes`
 - sandbox: `yes`
 - version: `nix-env (Nix) 2.1.3`
 - channels(alexey): `"nixos-17.03-17.03.1949.78e9665b48f, nixos-17.09-17.09.3238.e984f9e48e1"`
 - channels(root): `"nixos-18.09.1853.c2950341d03"`
 - nixpkgs: `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos`
```

```
$ tree /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/alexey/channels
/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/alexey/channels
├── binary-caches
│   ├── nixos-17.03 -> /nix/store/kzd027j27bifzi82339isf6rzir2g1hq-nixos-17.03-17.03.1949.78e9665b48f/binary-caches/nixos-17.03
│   └── nixos-17.09 -> /nix/store/m7qgsz2wy9rgc7dpzsacybc9rw79pxxh-nixos-17.09-17.09.3238.e984f9e48e1/binary-caches/nixos-17.09
├── manifest.nix -> /nix/store/913gblkfnvb0sz130wm59s82jxwkp3b1-env-manifest.nix
├── nixos-17.03 -> /nix/store/kzd027j27bifzi82339isf6rzir2g1hq-nixos-17.03-17.03.1949.78e9665b48f/nixos-17.03
└── nixos-17.09 -> /nix/store/m7qgsz2wy9rgc7dpzsacybc9rw79pxxh-nixos-17.09-17.09.3238.e984f9e48e1/nixos-17.09
```

However, they are not shown with `nix-channel --list`, and I cannot remove them with `nix-channel --remove`:

```
$ nix-channel --list
$ sudo nix-channel --list
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-18.09
```

Is something broken on my system, or what could be the explanation?  How can I remove those per-user channels?

Comment: I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2675) about this for Nix.

Comment: Why is channel listing only shown when `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

Guesstimate: have you ran `nix-channel --update` since dropping them?  (not tested, etc.)  You've dropped all channels from your user, according to the output.

Comment: I've just tried it, without and with `sudo` (by the way, not sure if `sudo` is needed), and also i did `nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade`, but they still show up.

Comment: With sudo you operate on root's channel list, without it you operate on the user's channel list.

It might be bug that removing names doesn't really work.  I certainly did replace channel URL while keeping the name and that works but it's something else.

Comment: Could it be related to [this](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/1457) open issue about "Channel names with `.` or `-`"?

Comment: Could you suggest by any chance how to "manually" remove them without breaking anything?